# How to achieve Exactly Once semantics when archive kafka message into AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, offset

How to store kafka message data with partition offset in one S3 PutObject transaction to achieve Exactly Once semantics? Does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible. One way to do that is take control of the offset management.

Your consumer can read one message from Kafka at at time and put that as object in AWS, while doing that store offset + partition name as key in the AWS. Now lets say your client crashed. When it comes up next time you query S3 to find what is the last offset in S3 and start reading message from there. For additional protection before you put message in S3 check if object with that key (It would be better if your producer produces UUID for message and you can use that) exists in S3 if yes dont overwrite it instead skip the message.

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
     public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {}
     public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        Iterator<TopicPartition> topicPartitionIterator = partitions.iterator();
        while(topicPartitionIterator.hasNext()){
              TopicPartition topicPartition = topicPartitionIterator.next();
              System.out.println("Current offset is " + kafkaConsumer.position(topicPartition) + " committed offset is kafkaConsumer.committed(topicPartition) 
              System.out.println("Resetting offset to " + startingOffset);
              kafkaConsumer.seek(topicPartition, startingOffset);
           }
        }
      }
  });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, your idea is possible. But there maybe lots of offset+partition key in s3, query the last offset will be slower and slower. And check key exists in s3 is not easy too except for using some mem db. Further more, we need group s3 data in date time to restore data at specific date range when need. How to design s3 key then?